# Format a decimal number to (###,###.##) using Blackberry Java API

Tags: java, blackberry, formatter

I'm trying to do a pretty simple thing using Blackberry RIM API - I have a string `1000000`, that I want to format to `1,000,000.00`

I have tried two RIM API classes in order to do that, but none of them did what I actually need:

1)  [javax.microedition.global.Formatter](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/javax/microedition/global/Formatter.html)

```
String value = "1000000";  
float floatValue = Float.parseFloat(value);  
Formatter f = new Formatter(); //also tried with locale specified - Formatter("en")  
String result = f.formatNumber(floatValue, 2);
```

The result variable is `1000000.00` - it has decimal separator but is missing group separators (commas).

2)  [net.rim.device.api.i18n.MessageFormat](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.0.2api/net/rim/device/api/i18n/MessageFormat.html) (claims to be compatible with java.text.MessageFormat in Java's standard edition)

```
 String value = "1000000";  
 Object[] objs = {value};  
 MessageFormat mfPlain = new MessageFormat("{0}");  
 MessageFormat mfWithFormat = new MessageFormat("{0,number,###,###.##}");  
 String result1 = mfPlain.format(objs);  
 String result2 = mfWithFormat.format(objs);
```

result1: (when `mfWithFormat` code commented out) gives me just a plain `1000000` (as expected, but useless).
result2: throws `IllegalArgumentException`.

At this point I'm out of options what to try next...

Any suggestions?

Comment: what locale is it using? Can you try a different locale?

Comment: Blackberry documentation says: _This implementation of the Formatter class supports only locale-neutral formatting at this time._ so I'm not specifying locale in my example. I also tried using `en` locale but I got the same result. The locale of my simulator should be `en` or `en-US` I believe.

Comment: The Blackberry API documentation also says: ...(this class supports the string, date, and time element formats). So it doesn't support the number format.

Comment: Thanks Richard, I guess it explains why I was getting that `IllegalArgumentException`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: 
http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Format-a-decimal-number/m-p/763981#M142257

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you're going to have to write your own functions to do this.

Answer (score -1):

This works without the need of creating your own function:

```
String value = "1000000";

MessageFormat msgFormat = new MessageFormat("{0,number,###,###.00}");
String s = msgFormat.format(new Object[]{Integer.valueOf(value)}));
```

Make sure you pass an integer type instead of a string otherwise you'll get: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Number

Comment: Doesn't work. IllegalArgumentException on the constructor line.

Comment: I guess that depends on the API you're using. Works with java.text.MessageFormat of most Java versions. Didn't test on micro edition.

Comment: The question was asked about Blackberry RIM API, not J2ME. Please don't confuse the issue with code not tested on BlackBerry, where RIM have implemented standard API they quite often are incomplete or broken - as in this case.